# asp.net core 3.1 + react authentication AzureDB

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, single-page-application, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an application that includes React Client Side and Asp.net core 3.1 web api for Backend, I tried to add authentication with AzureAD for now only to authenticate no to authorize.

In the client side I used the msal library version 1.4 and on the server side I used nuget package of Microsoft.Identity.Web.
Every time the server side returns 401 and the logs indicate nothing.

Thank you for your help! I've added the logs and all the relevant code

```
[18:24:29 INF] Authorization failed.
[18:24:29 INF] Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
[18:24:29 INF] Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes (["Bearer"]).
[18:24:29 INF] AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged.
```

```js
import { UserAgentApplication} from "msal";


let msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "7e3d8e08-2b42-46a8-83c1-5167d636808e",
        redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000",
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/78820852-55fa-450b-908d-45c0d911e76b",
        navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: "localStorage",
        storeAuthStateInCookie: true
    }
}


var msalInstance = new UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);


export { msalInstance };
```

And later in another page I have this function:

```js
        const handleLoginClick = () => {
            const accessTokenRequest = {
                scopes: ["user.read"]
            }
            msalInstance.loginPopup(accessTokenRequest)
                .then(response => {
                    msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(accessTokenRequest).then(tokenReponse => {
                            console.log(tokenReponse);
                            localStorage.setItem('token', tokenReponse.accessToken);
                            handleLoginSuccess();
                        });
                });
        }
```

And finally sending the token in axios get request:

```js
var config = {
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Authorization': `Bearer` + token
        }
    };

    var response = await axios.get(`${SERVER_URL}/${API_Path}`, config, { timeout: 15000 });
```

On the Asp.net core web api I added in the Startup.cs file in ConfigureServices:

```
           services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration);

            services.AddControllers(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });
```

With Configuration:

```js
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx",
    "ClientId": "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx",
  }
```

And in the Configure method I added

```
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
```

Comment: Use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your token and provide a screenshot. You must ensure that the scope requested by the client application is consistent with the expected recipient of the token. Check your 'aud' to ensure that it is the api you want to call, and the reason for the 401 You may have used the wrong token or you have used a token that does not belong to the api to call the api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're requesting scopes for Microsoft Graph (*User.Read*). You need to request them for your web api. Follow the steps detailed in [A React & Redux single-page application authorizing an ASP.NET Core Web API to call MS Graph API on behalf of a signed-in user.](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-react-spa-dotnetcore-webapi-obo)